# Two way Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I have some code and I'm having problems trying to change the value of the class 'Player'

My XAML

```
<Rectangle x:Name="oChar" Fill="Orange" Height="32" Width="32" Canvas.Left="32" Canvas.Top="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Code behind:

```
    private Player myPlayer = new Player { left = 32, top = 128 };
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = myPlayer.top;
        myPlayer.top += 32;
    }
```

Class INotiftyProperty

```
    private int _top;

    public int top
    {

        get { return _top; }

        set { _top = value; OnPropertyChanged("top"); }

    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

First time doing stuff like WPF, any help on why the value wont change or any information would be great!

Comment: You have to bind to the `top` property with the mode TwoWay: `{Binding top, Mode=TwoWay}`

Comment: this.DataContext = myPlayer;

Comment: Thanks, that's working fine now... Was missing that last step after all I done so far haha, thansk Tony and Tico :)

Comment: ;) Nice work! WPF is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this.Datacontext =myPlayer;